# Customising WooCommerce "products" listing HTML layouts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I'm currently adapting the WooCommerce Storefront theme for a client and am struggling to change the layout for the woocommerce "products" widget that displays a list of given products. I believe the template for this is "plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-widget-product.php".

However, adding it to my theme's "themes/mytheme/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php" directory and adjusting it doesn't appear to work.

Essentially I need to change the default structure from this:

[image]

To This:

[image]

I must be missing something obvious, surely?

Comment: you definitely have the correct file mate so it must be your template setup you are using, have you set up child theme correctly? do any other woocomerce templates edit in the normal manner

Answer (score 1):

OK, so within WooCommerce there is "content-widget-product.php" which returns a product's details for one type of widget.

There is also "content-product.php" which returns a product for their main [Products] shortcode loop... the main loop that gets used on the shop page, etc.

Editing the content-product.php file and overriding its related WooCommerce functions achieved what I needed.

Hopefully, this might help someone else in the future and save a few hours of hunting around!

Comment: hi i am facing the same issue here, i would like to add that `content-product.php` only affects the main loop in Shop page, but doesnt affect any loops generated by `shortcode`, do you have any ideas how i can edit the loops generated by `shortcode` @Dezzamondo ?